# Trying to add two matrices with numbers entered as a string and then display solution, but trouble with stdin and stdout

Tags: python, matrix, stdout, stdin, sys

It's a programming task to enter two matrices using stdin and then display the result in stdout. I often found runtime error or no stdin or stdout to display while the program is running good.

This is my code for addition of two matrices.

```
       """The constraint is the numbers will be entered only without any 
          string to be seen on console and also that to be in the same
          fashion being each number input separated by a white space."""
          import sys

            def main():

            num1 = []
            num2 = []

            rc1 = raw_input().split(' ')
            rc1_arr = [int(z) for z in rc1]
            r1 = rc1_arr[0]
            c1 = rc1_arr[1]
            while(r1 != 0):
                    mat1 = raw_input().split(' ')
                    arr1 = [int(z1) for z1 in mat1]
                    num1.append(arr1)
                    r1=r1-1

            rc2 = raw_input().split(' ')
            rc2_arr = [int(z) for z in rc2]
            r2 = rc2_arr[0]
            c2 = rc2_arr[1]
            while(r2 != 0):
                    mat2 = raw_input().split(' ')
                    arr2 = [int(z2) for z2 in mat2]
                    num2.append(arr2)
                    r2=r2-1

            for i in range(max(rc1_arr[0],rc2_arr[0])):
                 for j in range(max(rc1_arr[1],rc2_arr[1])):
                     su = num1[i][j]+num2[i][j]
                     sys.stdout.write(str(su))
                     sys.stdout.write(" ")
                 sys.stdout.write("\n")

        main()

       """ while running in idle it looks like this
       ##The input part is:
       3 3         ## represents no. of rows and columns
       1 2 3       ## This is the matrix 1 of 3*3
       4 5 6
       7 8 9
       3 3         ## represents no. of rows and columns for second matrix
       1 1 1       ## This is the matrix 2 of 3*3
       1 1 1
       1 1 1
       ## And the output is like:
       2 3 4       ## Sum of the above two matrices.
       5 6 7 
       8 9 10
       """
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you please specify the input and output that you want.

Comment: @Ezio I have added some comment lines to show for the input and output to look into it...

Comment: Your program seem to work fine when the number of rows and columns of both the matrices are same. If the number of rows and columns of the two matrices differs then it will fail.

Comment: Yes the code is working fine but i need to give the input and output in stdin and stdout so that online interpreter will provide me some results... Also if you have identified the problem with unequal no. of rows and columns, will you please suggest a trick to remove it...

Comment: Declare two arrays of same number of rows and columns. 
Number of rows = max(rc1_arr[0],rc2_arr[0])
Number of columns = max(rc1_arr[1],rc2_arr[1]).
Initialize both the arrays with 0 and then take entries with the user and fill the corresponding cells.The cells which does not get any entries will contain 0 and hence the addition remains the same.

Comment: @Ezio I found my error in the last second for loop where I am giving unnecessary space after the last element of first row... And now my program is running smoothly... Thanks for your help... :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have some problem with the indentation... I did not touch a line (other than adjust the indentation and it work as expected!)

```
#!/usr/bin/env pyhton2
import sys

def main():

    num1 = []
    num2 = []

    rc1 = raw_input().split(' ')
    rc1_arr = [int(z) for z in rc1]
    r1 = rc1_arr[0]
    c1 = rc1_arr[1]
    while(r1 != 0):
        mat1 = raw_input().split(' ')
        arr1 = [int(z1) for z1 in mat1]
        num1.append(arr1)
        r1=r1-1

    rc2 = raw_input().split(' ')
    rc2_arr = [int(z) for z in rc2]
    r2 = rc2_arr[0]
    c2 = rc2_arr[1]
    while(r2 != 0):
        mat2 = raw_input().split(' ')
        arr2 = [int(z2) for z2 in mat2]
        num2.append(arr2)
        r2=r2-1

    for i in range(max(rc1_arr[0],rc2_arr[0])):
        for j in range(max(rc1_arr[1],rc2_arr[1])):
            su = num1[i][j]+num2[i][j]
            sys.stdout.write(str(su))
            sys.stdout.write(" ")
        sys.stdout.write("\n")

main()
```

Comment: I knew that the code is running fine but I want the inputs by stdin and outputs in stdout. This is the real task. Even the IDEONE online interpreter is not producing results with this...

Comment: What do you mean with stdin and stdout then? Do you mean redirection from a file (stuff.py < input.txt)? Your code is working reading on stdin and writing on stdout...